# Is WUBI off topic?

Tags: discussion

Does this site still answer questions on WUBI ?

WUBI no longer works on win 8+, I don't see too many questions pop up about it these days, but, should I flag them as off topic ? Many users have Win 7 and WUBI works there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The short answer

`wubi` is a bit like leaded petrol: yes, back in the time it was a great idea and solved some unique problems, but on the other hand, it also created some new ones, so better leave it where it belongs: in history.

### The long answer

`wubi` doesn't support UEFI, so it doesn't support *some* Win7 and definitely *no* Win8, Win10 OEM-installed Windows versions.  Also, the last Ubuntu that came with `wubi` out of the box was 13.10 (which is EOL).

Having said all that, this is a free, libre and open community and you can do whatever you want: if you want to support it, *go ahead* and if you take a strong stance that you *will* support it, I even want to help you and I'll send all `wubi`-related questions, that I come across, to you from the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room)  here: just drop by once every 24 hours so that your handle gets remembered by the room.

Me, on the other hand, all dressed up in an encounter suit, won't touch it even when armed with a 10-foot pole *and a [PPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phased_plasma_gun)* ...  **;-)**

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I too am not a component of WUBI so won't be answering questions on it directly as I have no experience with it, guess it is still on topic here, so I will just let the questions be.

Comment: I hope you're neither a *com*ponent nor a *pro*ponent of `wubi`.  IMHO if you see `wubi` and Windows 7/8/10: duplicate to: [How to Install Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)